# AOT build with file-loader outputPath turns img tag into string

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular2-aot, webpack-file-loader

I am encoutering an issue when trying to build a AOT build with the file-loader `outputPath` option on. The resulting output is a `<img>` tag surrounded with quote marks (`"<img src=images/world.png alt=world />"`).

This only happens in my AOT build and not in my Dev build. So I am guessing the file-loader is cut of during it's compilation cycle and the resulting string is inserted.

**Versions:**

```
Angular: 4.4.4
@ngtools/webpack: 1.7.2,
file-loader: 1.1.5,
image-webpack-loader: 3.4.2,
webpack: 3.6.0,
webpack-dev-server: 2.9.1
```

**webpack.common.js  | rules section**

```
   module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    caseSensitive: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader', // Image loader
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'images/' // Fails with AOT build. <img> tag gets turned into a string
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff2?|ttf)([?]?.*)$/, // Font loader
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // Uglyfy the JavaScript output | Still gives a small win with AOT build
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true
            },
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            comments: false
        }),
        new AotPlugin({ // Create AOT build
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
            entryModule: __dirname + '/src/app/app.module#AppModule'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // Set the node env so that the project knows what to enable or disable
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

Is this a bug or just something that I am doing wrong? And if it's a bug, on which side is it a bug, `@ngtools/webpack` or `file-loader`?

Any help is appreciated!

---

**My app.html for reference**

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <img src="../assets/world.png" alt="world"/>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: The output html]

---

**Update**

It seems to be a bug in the AOT compiler of Angular. So I made a [Bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7956). There is a workarround in the comments below, but it would be nice if there would be a fix to this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug.  The reason its rendered as a string is because there are no quotes around the URL.

The work-around is to add the quotes through the html-loader plugin:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader', options: {
    removeAttributeQuotes: false
  }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: This worked! To bad it is a workarround and not a correct solution. I've made a ticket on the github page if Angular to see if anyone knows a fix (added the link to the post)